# IE leaving unnecessary space after image

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-table, html-email

I am creating an HTML email as

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
  <img src="image.jpg" width="x" height="y" style="margin:0; padding:0; display:block;">
 </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
 <p>Para with lots of text</p>
</tr>
</table>
```

However an unnecessary space is left at the bottom of the image when seen in Internet Explorer. How can I get rid of this space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a bug or anything like that.

Depending on the doctype in use, different browsers apply specific values to margin, padding, and border to various elements.

Looking at your code I don't see where you set the border on the image to 0.  Do this.

Generally speaking the best doctype to use is simply `<!DOCTYPE html>`  This results in standards mode across pretty much all browsers.  Once you have that there are only a few minor tweaks (such as image border) that you need to do to ensure total compliance.

Next, a paragraph tag is invalid inside of a TR.  You are missing a TD as Sparky672 pointed out.

Comment: I had a similar issue. To fix, I did as you said: added "<!DOCTYPE html>". Next, I added a line-height CSS rule to the <td> and the unwanted vertical space disappeared as desired.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML for your `<table>` element is wrong.  You're missing the second set of `<td></td>` tags.

Also, the `<p></p>` will put some space above and below your text caption. (**Edit:**  Although a technically true statement that the `<p>` element has a built-in top/bottom margin, the `<p>` is not causing the OP's problem)

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="image.jpg" width="x" height="y" style="margin:0; padding:0; display:block;">
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             Para with lots of text
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The space still remains after the <p> is removed.

Comment: @user1212- That may be true, but a P tag has a built-in margin for top & bottom unless you remove it with CSS.  So my answer contains a technically true statement even if you still have something else causing your problem.  What about fixing the table's HTML?

Answer (score 0):

could it be the `<p>` tag that is giving you the space after the image and before the text?

Comment: Its not the <p> tag. The space still remains after the paragraph is removed

Answer (score 0):

Why have a `<p>` inside of a `table`?  It's just going to put it above the table.  IE probably is showing the empty `<tr></tr>`.  You might need a `<td>` around your `<p>`

What happens when you don't use a table at all and just show the image?

Comment: Why use a table?  Why not do: `<p>Para with lots of text</p><p><img /></p>`

Comment: While I agree that putting `<p>` blocks inside a table is not the best method, your statement, _"It's just going to put it above the table."_ is technically incorrect.  A `<p>` inside a table cell will stay inside the table cell.

Comment: @Sparky672, you're right.  I guess I was just trying to say, use a table like it should be used, or use a couple <p> tags.  Mixing them can be hairy.

Comment: Yes, `<table>` elements should be left for tabulating data and CSS used for layouts.

Answer (score -2):

I believe IE has a bug that inserts unnecessary space after an image when placed inside a table. Try removing ALL whitespace in between your tags:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td><img src="image.jpg" width="x" height="y" /></td></tr>
<tr>
 <td><p>Para with lots of text</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Yea, it's ugly, but that's in part why tables are not the preferred method for layout design. Hope this works for you.

Comment: I'm aware whitespace should be ignored, hence bug. Or, if you prefer, an issue, or oddity?...which we know IE is full of. I don't know if this still occurs in most recent versions of IE, but definitely older versions.

Comment: @Sparky672: Depends on the doctype/browser..  However, this is still not a correct answer as it is not a bug.

Comment: Pretty much every rendering difference out there boils down to incorrect doctype usage coupled with ignorance of the difference between the various modes: strict, almost strict, quirks, ...  You might want to review: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html  When in quirks mode all bets are off and you are at the mercy of the browser developers and generally need various hacks to make things look the same due to differences in the box model and default values.  When in strict, there's really only two main tags you need to concern yourself with: image and overflow.